# Multiclassification in Python using keras error

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am new to python and try multiclassification on iris.csv dataset having 100 instances and 9 columns .I got this error and search this error and apply solution but nothing work for me.. please help

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "iris.py", line 48, in
>   
>       model.fit(X, dummy_y, epochs=200, batch_size=5)   File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 871,
>   in fit
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)   File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1525, in fit
>       batch_size=batch_size)   File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1383, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='target')   File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 144, in _standardize_input_data
>       str(array.shape)) ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (100L, 3L)

here is my code

```
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("iris.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:,0:8].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,8]
print(X)
print(Y)

#encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)


# convert integers to dummy variables (hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
print(dummy_y)


# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))


# Compile model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


#model.fit
model.fit(X, dummy_y, epochs=200, batch_size=5)


#print("Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

Comment: share the dataset

Comment: https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_irisdss/downloads/IRIS.csv/ dataset link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Change your loss function to `categorical_crossentropy`.

**Solution 2:**
Use `encoded_Y` to train your model. `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` doesn't need hot encoded labels.